# SSIS For Each loop based on records

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I want to accomplish a fairly simple task (I'd think).

I have one table with a shiftid (INT), shiftstart (datetime), shiftend (datetime).

I'd like to query that table, then run a query (on an entirely different database) that asks for production (which is calculated in an odd way - requiring three separate queries) using the start and end times, and store that in the original database with the shiftid and a production amount for the shift.

I've tried to do this using a Foreach Loop and a script task that builds a variable that would contain the query, but I'm continually hitting a brick wall there.

```
Dts.Variables("User::SQLshiftstart").Value = "SELECT value FROM[dbo].[AnalogHistory] WHERE TagName = 'Z_HISTFMZ_P2_0004' AND DateTime = '" & Dts.Variables("User::shiftstart").ToString
```

I keep getting an error - "Command text was not set for the command object". And googling that error doesn't push me any further down the path.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I decided to go a different way instead of using a script object to build a variable. I actually created the variable in my SELECT:

```
SELECT (CONCAT
('SELECT CAST(value AS DECIMAL(10,4)) AS beg FROM [dbo].[AnalogHistory] WHERE TagName = ''Z_HISTDATA_P1_0007'' AND DateTime = '' ', 
DateAdd(hh,-6,shiftstart),
' '' AND wwTimeZone = ''UTC'' '))
```

This way, I avoid having to build an intermediate script object and can directly query based on the variable name in my FOREACH loop.